# SetupCheckbox ID from DB value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, checkbox

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Category" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLDataSourceBenefitCategory" >

         <ItemTemplate>                    
               <li>                           
                   <asp:CheckBox  ID = "filterid"+'<%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ClientBenefitSectionheadingID","filterID{0}" ) %>' runat="server" value='<%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ClientBenefitSectionheadingID","bencat{0}" ) %>' class = "dynamicFilterInput" AutoPostBack="True"  Checked="True"  /> 


                          </li>                             
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Hi,

I have the above code I Would like my checkbox to have as ID = "filter"+value from db. When I try to get value from db per code above I get error. Could anyone advise me the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to do that? and you've not included the error...

Comment: Can you do this in the code-behind?